# How to destroy a progressbar on dialog closing?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I have these 2 functions one of them is to create a dialog and the other is to destroy a progressbar,

after i create the dialog i might need to create a progress bar inside it and start it, but when i close the dialog, the progress bar keeps running in the back ground.
what i need is to destroy or do anything to stop this progress bar from working.
I wrote the createdialog function with a beforeclose event to destroy the progress bar but it doesn't work, and the dialog is not even closing, like the close button is none responsive.

```
function createdialog(trgt,h,w) {
    $( trgt ).dialog({
        height:h,
        width:w,
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 200
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 100
        },
        beforeClose: function( event, ui ) {
                destroyprogresspar(trgt);
        }
    });
}

destroyprogresspar(dialg) {
    if(dialg=="#myfilesdialog") { 
        $("#progressbar").progressbar("destroy");
    } else if(dialg=="#ibrowser") {
        $("#progressbar2").progressbar("destroy");
    }
}
```

i tried making a closing handler upon creating the dialog like this (**WORKS BUT MESSY**):

```
$(trgt).on("dialogbeforeclose", function( event, ui ) {
    if(trgt=="#myfilesdialog") {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar("destroy");
    } else if(trgt=="#ibrowser") {
        $("#progressbar2").progressbar("destroy");
    } 
});
```

and it works but can't make it call a function instead the if conditions like this (**DOESN'T WORK**):

```
$(trgt).on("dialogbeforeclose", function( event, ui ) {
    destroyprogresspar(trgt);
});
```

Comment: Have you debugged and verified that `progressbar("destroy")` is getting called?

Comment: Try adding close handler to dialog like this:  `.dialog({   close: function(event, ui) { $(this).remove();}   });`

Comment: Abhijit Kadam I edited the question with your suggession...